# How to screen record iOS-real device with command?

Tags: ios, appium, screen-recording, xcrun, simctl

I need to screen record iOS from iMAC for the purpose of test automation.
I found commands for Android and iOS-Simulator which are:

> - adb screenrecord /sdcard/123.mp4
> - xcrun simctl io  recordVideo --type=mp4

However, I need a command for iOS-real device.

The purpose of this is for taking video of device during each of test automation sessions.

Comment: Probably you can use Automator or Apple Script and use QuickTime to do a screen recording of the device.

Comment: `xcrun simctl io recordVideo` doesn't record audio

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11 has built-in Screen Recording for real devices, you need to check if its possible to do run/stop/getFile from device via command line tools or whatever using in terminal.

In addition, its possible to use `QuickTime + Applescript` for screen recording, check [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/can-applescript-be-used-to-automate-a-screen-recording-session-on-os-x) for details.

Comment: I have checked what is built-in Screen Recording in iOS11.

Comment: However, since I am quite new to iOS developing, it is really hard to find the way you told to me.

Comment: hey John, after some research I found its possible via QuickTime, I updated answer.

Comment: Hey @dmle Thank you for the answer, I also tried that one, but it is recording macos's screen, not ios's screen.

Comment: I have found [this](https://github.com/isonic1/flick), but I am still finding. Because this is 1fps video.

Comment: Is it possible to use the iOS Simulator to record video and audio with this technique?