# iOS Simulator, recording video and audio via the command line?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, simctl

I'm trying to create an app preview video using the iOS command line simulator tool, which produces video, like so.

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo
```

However, videos don't include audio. I have seen that videos aren't possible unless you have support for metal, which I do.

I've seen some conflicting answers, although mentions the mic [Is it possible to record actual sound on the simulator using mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090128/is-it-possible-to-record-actual-sound-on-the-simulator-using-mic)

I need to automate this process as I have a lot of videos (languages / devices) where I need to produce videos ( I can provided more details about this).

I'm currently using an automated UI Test to run through my app and produce the video.

I've also seen a method using applescript and quicktime player, but this doesn't appear to work with the simulator and I'll have problems using automated tests.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/can-applescript-be-used-to-automate-a-screen-recording-session-on-os-x

[How to screen record iOS-real device with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279619/how-to-screen-record-ios-real-device-with-command)

Alternatively I'm looking to record the audio from my app separatly from the simulator perhaps using something like soundflower. However I will need to do this from the command line / script. Then I'll have to join them together from the command line.

Comment: We don't currently record the audio. You'd have to record it separately then merge it with the recorded video. If you'd like to indicate your interest in this feature please file an enhancement request. It will probably get duped to an existing radar but it is still helpful to know the interest level.

Comment: Yeah I’ve already raised a radar, is this enough https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4929896522448896

Comment: Yes, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I've given up using the simulator. I've tried again in Xcode 11.1, but there's still no sound, and video recording doesn't work on iOS13 simulators atm. I ended up using ReplayKit, but ReplayKit requires real devices... For the devices I don't have access to, I simply scale the videos. I wrote a blog post with the process: http://endavid.com/index.php?entry=81

Comment: I made some changes to snapshot on a branch https://github.com/JulesMoorhouse/fastlane/tree/snapshot-record-video-with-audio